# ngroute in Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-route

I am tryin to use ngRoute to marry customers.html along with customersController.js to show up in the view when index.html is loaded.

It should show a list of customers in a table along with some other properties.

What it shows is a partial view.

The link for the code: http://plnkr.co/YzZ3ldemD8UHH0R16BNi

index.html has the following code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="customersApp">
<head>
<title>Testing ngRoute</title>
</head>
<body>

    <div ng-view></div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.1/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.1/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<script src="app.js"></script>
<script src="customersController.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

app.js has the following code

```
(function() {

    var app = angular.module('customersApp', ['ngRoute']);

    app.config(function($routeProvider){
        $routeProvider
            .when('/', {
                controller: 'CustomersController',
                templateUrl: 'customers.html'   
            })
            .otherwise( { redirectTo: '/' });

});

}());
```

customersController.js has the following code

```
app.controller('CustomersController', function ($scope){
        $scope.sortBy= 'name';
        $scope.reverse  = false;

        $scope.customers=[{joined: '2000-12-02', name:'John', city:'Sacramento', orderTotal:7.554},
                {joined: '2012-12-07', name:'Tom', city:'Chandler', orderTotal:110.57},
                {joined: '1997-05-02', name:'Matt', city:'Michigan', orderTotal:19.993},
                {joined: '2001-10-08', name:'Jane', city:'New York', orderTotal:112.954}];
        $scope.doSort = function(propName){
            $scope.sortBy = propName;
            $scope.reverse = !$scope.reverse;
        };
});
```

customers.html(the view) has the following code

```
<h2>Customers</h2>
Filter: <input type="text" ng-model="customersFilter.name"/>
<br /><br />
<table>
    <tr>
        <th ng-click="doSort('name')">Name</th>
        <th ng-click="doSort('city')">City</th>
        <th ng-click="doSort('orderTotal')">Order Total</th>
        <th ng-click="doSort('joined')">Joined</th>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="cust in customers | filter:customersFilter | orderBy:sortBy:reverse">
        <td>{{cust.name}}</td>
        <td>{{cust.city}}</td>
        <td>{{cust.orderTotal | currency}}</td>
        <td>{{cust.joined | date:'longDate'}}</td>
    </tr>
    </table>
<br />
<span>Total customers: {{customers.length}}</span>
```

Comment: I don't see a problem after you remove the superfluous `(function () { ... })();` around the definition of `app` in `app.js`: http://plnkr.co/edit/2E91sOIKmfql6IbLHQ0G?p=preview

Comment: Iffe's are friends not superfluous.  http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The app variable leaves scope when you resolve the iife.  So when you try to attach the controller to it, it no longer exists.  Change the controller to 
    `angular.module('customersApp').controller('CustomersController', function ($scope){`

As a side note, controllers can also be wrapped in iife's!